# Angular2 RC5 tutorial : Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angularjs

Following the Angular 2 ["Hero tour" tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html), I encounter the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:  
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    "): AppComponent@6:13 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

My *package.json* content is:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.17",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

*app.module.ts* content:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

And app.component content :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    hero: Hero = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Windstorm'
    };
}
```

I spent time to read and apply solutions proposed in similar question on stackoverflow with no success.

What could be wrong?

Solution :

use

```
//main entry point
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './app';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

instead of :

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Comment: Could you add your app.module file ?

Comment: Two possibilities that jump to my mind is 1) the input is missing a name and 2) You are missing `FormsModule` in your `app.module` file.

Comment: As you can see FormsModule is imported

Comment: Hum. I didn't see any errors... Could you show us your app.component please ?

Comment: app.component added to the main post

Comment: I don't understand why :/ 
I've created a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/1AWdaztRO8YL6olj3agj?p=preview

That's exactly what you give us and it's working

Comment: I found the problem by seeing your Plunker, I was wrong in main.ts file. Main post edited with the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Your app.module.ts should look like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, provideForms, disableDeprecatedForms } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms()],
})

export class AppModule { }
```

UPDATE: this is now obsolete with RC6 and beyond

Answer (score 2):

In **RC6** it looks like this:

```js
...
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ ..., FormsModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

I.e. `provideForms`, `disableDeprecatedForms` are removed as deprecated. Check https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md for details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for it, unless that part...nothing going on!

`import { FormsModule, provideForms, disableDeprecatedForms } from '@angular/forms';`

Answer (score 0):

A similar error occurs if you don't update the app.modules.ts file as required.
That is adding the following import

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
```

and the FormsModule as follows:

```
imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
```

Answer (score 0):

The app works fine. But I had this error in tests. You should import FormsModule in app.component.spec.ts like in app.module.ts to fix this.